# Progressive Flat rate shipping method based on item quantity in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fee, shipping-method

I Would like to add different progressive flat rates shipping cost for 2 different shipping Zones **domestic** and **international**: A fixed amount for the first item and an additional cost for every additional items.

**eg:** Standard domestic postage $10, and $20 international, with $5 additional for each extra item.

Is this possible through woocommerce shipping setting? or this need some custom coding?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following cost line that will give you a fixed cost + an additional cost by item. This need to be differently for each shipping zone.

1. For your "**Domestic**" shipping Zone, use: **`5+([qty]*5)`** 
    
    So the first item will be at **`10`** *`(5+5)`* and each additional item will add **`+5`** to the cost.

   [image]
2. For your "**International**" shipping Zone, use: **`15+([qty]*5)`** 
    
    So the first item will be at **`20`** *`(15+5)`* and each additional item will add **`+5`** to the cost..

   [image]